Bode diagram of rauch filter
I want to find the bode diagram of this transfer function:
Let \$H(p) = -\frac{R_6 C_2 p}{1+R_5(C_2+C_3)p+R_5 R_6 C_2 C_3 p^2}\$
First i start by identifying this system into this form : \$H(p) = A \frac{\frac{2\varepsilon \cdot p}{\omega_0}}{1+\frac{2\varepsilon \cdot p}{\omega_0} + (\frac{p}{\omega_0})^2}\$
;\$A=\frac{-R_6 C_2}{R_5 (C_2+C_3)} , \varepsilon = \frac{\sqrt{R_5}(C_2+C_3)}{2\sqrt{R_6 C_2 C_3}}, \omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R_5 R_6 C_2 C_3}}\$
The next steps are finding the bode asymptots for both the gain & phase : \$L(\omega) = 20 \log{|H(j \omega)|} \land \phi(\omega) = arg(H(j \omega))\$
so \$L(\omega) = 20\log(|\frac{2 A \varepsilon}{\omega_0}|) + 20 \log(|\omega|) - 10\log((1- \frac{\omega}{\omega_0})^2 - (\frac{2\varepsilon \omega}{\omega_0})^2) \$
\$\phi(\omega) = 90° - \arctan(\frac{\frac{2\varepsilon \omega}{\omega_0}}{1- \frac{\omega}{\omega_0}})\$
Is this valid?

What does $p$ represent?

@Andyaka $p = j \omega$ thought its obvious nop?

@HellBoy What book follows this convention? I have never seen p represent complex frequency. I have only ever seen either $H(s)$ and $H(j\omega)$, never $H(p)$.

french books @Carl

p is used to represent the derivative operator in operational calculus (associated with Oliver Heaviside). It becomes j*omega when the signals are sinusoids. And s when the signals are exponentials. There are more methods than are dreamed of in your philosophy.

idk why y'all goin around the question nit-picking on notations smh, nvm i'll delete the question

There is no clear evidence of a question in your post and no, it's not at all obvious to English speakers.

Read first line in the post, how come switching $ s $ to $ p $ would be a dramatic change, are all english speakers this dramatic on notation change? @Andyaka

It wasn't clear that p was a complex number because you called it p. On the other hand if you called it s then it would be obvious and no, you haven't asked a question.

Let me see if I can add my modest contribution to this debate. First off, there is nothing wrong with the \$p\$ notation. It is widely used in Europe and I learned it this way in university. I then switched to \$s\$ and stuck with it since then. Funny enough, if you read Network Analysis and Feedback Amplifier Design, the author, Hendrik Bode, uses \$p\$ in his equations ^_^ See this excerpt from his book:

Now, regarding your expression, I would suggest to format it a little bit differently, by factoring the zero from the numerator. That way, you obtain a true low-entropy form as described in my book on transfer functions. If you do this, then the leading term is the peaking gain at \$\omega_0\$, and from the \$Q\$ factor, you can deduce the 3-dB frequencies quite easily:

I have used arbitrary time constants values to plot the graphs but the right side shows how to draw an asymptotic representation. Is it is what you were looking for?

Infinite thanks !! thats what i wanted to hear!!!

Hello HellBoy, glad if I could help! Sometimes, rewriting the equation the right way helps a lot.

I mean, , do I know better than the professor who asked to write it that way? hahahha but regardless, idk why amazon doesnt ship to my place lol?

Also regarding the frequency & resistor & capacitor values, i had picked : $F_0 = \frac{\omega_0}{2 \pi} = 1kHz $ and $R_5 = 1k\Omega , R_6 = 100k \Omega, C_3 = 47nF$ so it might be a bit different my bode diagram

No problem, I will update the results with your values. What is the value for $C_2$ then?

$ \omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R_5 R_6 C_2 C_3}} \iff C_2 = \frac{1}{\omega_0 ^2 \cdot (R_5 R_6 C_3)}  = 5.39 nF$

Voilà, the graph is updated.

Infinite thanks would've double upvoted but unfortunately only one is allowed, but can you please tell me the logic behind the formula of $Q $ and $H_0 $

With pleasure : ) If you equal $1+sb_1+s^2b_2$ with $1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2$ and solve for $Q$ and $\omega_0$ then you have what I gave. For $H_0$, factor the zero on top and you find my formula again.

Niiice i see it , i will do effort to find the band pass frequency of it

My professor said the phase plot shouldnt be negative tho

To draw the asymptotic Bode plots, the values ​​of the devices present in the network would be needed.

the breaking points of the diagram are the poles of H.

Good answer but unfortunately not the way i want to identify the transfert function, instead i want it the way its expressed in my original question

I assume you want to plot the straight line approximations of the magnitude and phase response of the system described by your transfer function. To do this, you need the component values. It cannot be done analytically.
This is because the approximations for a single real pole (or zero) and for a pair of complex conjugates poles (or zeroes) are different. For example, the magnitude approximation for a complex conjugated pole pair has a peak (if the damping ratio is below \$1/\sqrt{2}\$) while the magnitude approximation for a real pole does not have a peak. To determine whether the pole locations are real or complex you need the component values.

Our professor solved it without this "complication" , my fault for not attending, i'll check somewhere else thx , +1 for effort

I tried to put the transfer function in the required form, but it seems to me that the numerator coefficient is a little different:


I already made it into the requested form, im asking for the bode diagram
